# TwinCat images have blue background

Tags: plc, twincat, twincat-hmi, beckhof

I am developing a small HMI for a beckhoff PLC/HMI running TwinCat3. The PLC I am running is the CP6606-0001-0020 which is a 7-inch economy panel PC (straight from the website ;) ).

I have developed the HMI using TwinCat Visualisation and am trying to use icons to enhance the useability of the HMI.

The expected HMI design should look like the following picture, but it is just not coming out like that. I'm not sure if this is due to a limitation of the device, a configuration option that I need to set or something else.

[image: Screenshot of desired HMI design]
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YjCKr.png) The Desired Image

[image: Screenshot of the obtained HMI]
[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RXUPH.png) The Obtained Image

For the second image, I used Paint to illustrate the result obtained as the problematic design is only showing on the HMI and I don't know how to take screenshots from the actual PLC.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

PS: If anyone with enough reputation sees this, please create a Beckhoff tag that is spelt correctly. The only one I could find was Beckhof (one 'f') and I don't really like that I had to use a tag that was spelt wrong.

EDIT: The Solution was to not use the default VisuSymbols library that comes with TwinCat3, but instead to create custom icons, and then create an image pool with those items loaded. And then use those in the image container.

[image: The solved result]

Comment: I don't know much about this HMI model, but I've had similar problems due to the type of image used (bmp, jpeg), I solved it by changing the icons to PNG, have you tried?

Comment: I was using the default icons that come from the Visu-Symbols library (should have mentioned that), but maybe I will just get custom icons in PNG format and try them. Thanks.

Comment: I created PNG icons and used them in the Visualisation and it worked perfectly. Thanks. If you put your comment as an answer, I will mark it as the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know much about this HMI model, but I've had similar problems due to the type of image used (bmp, jpeg), I solved it by changing the icons to PNG.